# DEL key not wrapping to the next line in Vim normal mode

Tags: vim

It does so in Insert mode but in Normal mode both the Del key and 'x' dont let me erase beyond the end of the current line and even starts deleting backwards.
Is there a way to change that ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`backspace` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backspace') option controls the behavior.  You can try adding this to your `.vimrc`

```
backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Comment: unfortunately backspace option does not control DEL